# When to say LeDovid HaShem Ori in a minyan with different nusach

Tags: tefilla, minhag, elul, nusach-sefard, nusach-ashkenaz

I daven Nusach Ashkenaz saying “*LeDovid HaShem Ori*” at Shacharis and Maariv.

Q1 If I daven Mincha with a Minyan which says “*LeDovid HaShem Ori*” at Mincha, should I say it with them? (I assume yes, in order not to separate myself from the Tzibbur).

Q2 If I then daven Maariv in the same Minyan (which now does not say “*LeDovid HaShem Ori*”), am I obliged to say it? I realise that this is a case for CYLOR and will do iy”H.

Comment: +1. But I'd have asked Q2 the other way around: If I've already said it at _maariv_ because I was with an _Ashk'naz_ group, need I say it at _mincha_ with that same group if I'm a _nusach S'farad_ user? (The way you ask it seems to assuming _mincha_ comes before _maariv_.)

Comment: @msh210, are there those who daven maariv before mincha?  Maybe I'm misunderstanding you.  As to the question, would there ever be an issur on reciting tehillim (assuming one is in a place where one could learn Torah in the first place)?  Also, for what it's worth, some nusach Sefard put L'Dovid at Shachris and Maariv.

Comment: @yoel, everyone says _maariv_ before _mincha_. The first time _nusach Ashk'naz_ says "_L'david_" is at _maariv_ of the first of _Elul_.

Comment: @msh210 ohhh... of course, you are right.  I was imagining you meant that a kehila might daven maariv and then mincha, but of course what you meant was that the order of the prayers is maariv, shachris, mincha.

Comment: The question was written as it occurred today, first at mincha then at maariv.

Comment: But @msh210's point is, you could discuss replacing the *l'David* from Arvit, with Mincha on the next day. If you said it in Arvit, then again in Mincha the next day, this would have no affect on the next Arvit - which is a seperate day, and a separate set of tfillot.

Comment: @AviD. Got it. Thank you. My Rav said similarly to WAF's OR.

Comment: Nusach Ahskenaz is not to say LeDovid Hashem Ori at any tefilloh as it just does not come up. Nusach Polin took on the Sephardi minhag of saying it during Elul and Tishrei (until Shemini Atzeres) based on the Hasidic influences in Eastern Europe.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I CMLOR many years ago on the predicament I found myself in davening *mincha* and *ma'ariv* in the same two places every day. The former was *nusach Ashkenaz* and the latter *nusach S'farad*. The result was that the *tzibur* around me was effectively saying it only once a day. He said tersely and with a shrug, "it's just a *perek* of *T'hilim*."

Although there is an interesting depth to this answer, the implication was that one has nothing to lose by saying Psalm 27 at any time, especially if there is a group reciting it where he is. On the other hand there may be something to lose - as you mentioned - by deviating from the practice of those around you.