# Specifics of when to say L'Dovid Hashem Ori

Tags: prayer-book, elul, nusach-sefard

My siddur says:

```
 מן ר”ח אלול עד אחר שמיני עצרת בערב ובבוקר אומרים זה
                ויש נוהגין לאמרו קודם ח”ק שאחר שמו”ע

 From Rosh Chodesh Elul until after Shmini Atzeres, 
 in the evening and in the morning, we say this.  
 Some have the custom to say it before the Chatzi Kaddish after Shmone Esre.
```

Although the common custom in Nusach Sefard is to say this at Shachris and Mincha, it seems to me that by "evening and morning" the siddur is saying to follow the Ashkenaz custom of saying at Maariv and Shachris.  Could it possibly be understood to be referring to Mincha rather than Maariv?  Secondly, is it safe to assume that it is placed after both Shmone Esre and Tachanun, directly preceding Chatzi Kaddish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"בערב" could, I think, mean at *mincha*, especially among *Nusach S'farad* users, who often say *mincha* late. I wouldn't infer too much (e.g. that it means *maariv*) from the choice of words there.

I think it'd be safe to say, based on that description, that some recite it after *tachanun* before *chatzi kadish* — but I've never seen this done. In every congregation that I've been in (AFAIR), it was said either after "*Alenu*" or after *shir shel yom*. If it was after "*Alenu*", there was a *kadish yasom* before and after it; if it was after *shir shel yom*, there was a *kadish yasom* after it and, in some congregations, before it.

---

*Edit:* I'm informed in a comment (below, by [yoel](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/802/yoel)) that my "I've never seen this done", above, is due only to my lack of exposure: that, in fact, some communities that are originally from the Ukraine have this custom.

Comment: Saying it after tachanun seems to be a custom of various Ukrainian Chasiduses, namely Breslev, Chernobyl, Skver, and Berditchev. (I'm assuming on the last one because the siddur in question is Tefila Yeshara, the Berditchever siddur)  My inference regarding maariv was not based only on the word "erev" (although you make a good point regarding this) but also on the order "b'erev u'v'voker", which, to me, could only be understood as referring to the services as they occur, as we discussed [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9738/).

Comment: @yoel, oh, good point about the order: I hadn't noted that. That it refers to _maariv_ is more strongly indicated than I'd realized, but is still not _muchrach_ (necessary) IMO.

Comment: Saying it after immediately after tachanun is also the custom of (at least some) Vizhnitzer kehillos.